# Impleneting general function for generic interface

Tags: c#-4.0, interface, generics

**EDIT** *Mistyped property name in example*

Let's assume we have interfaces like this

```
public interface IBase {}
public interface IItf_1: IBase {}
public interface IItf_2: IBase {}
public interface IItf_3: IBase {}

public interface IInterfaceHolder<T>: IBase, INotifyPropertyChanged {
  // Changes to this property caused raise of the PropertyChanged event
  bool Checked { get; set; }
  T Item { get; }
}

public interface ISomeFunnyInterface: INotifyPropertyChanged {
  IEnumerable<IInterfaceHolder<IItf_1>> Collection_1 { get; }
  IEnumerable<IInterfaceHolder<IItf_2>> Collection_2 { get; }
  IEnumerable<IInterfaceHolder<IItf_3>> Collection_3 { get; }
}
```

The idea is to tunnel the PropertyChanged from each Checked property to PropertyChaned raised from ISomeFunnyInterface with corresponding property name (some other than 'Checked').

The obvious solution is to handle each PropertyChanged send by interface IInterfaceHolder. But the problem is when I write the handler:

```
private void GenericSelectorSelected_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    dynamic el = (dynamic)sender;

    // here an exception is thrown, because sender (or more correctly 'el') is
    // handled as IBase, and not as IInterfaceHolder
    if (el.Checked) {
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem? How to make it work without the need of writing separated handlers for each IInterfaceHandler<.>

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a general interface implementation instead of what you are doing you could use [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) (available via nuget). It allows you to subclass a DynamicObject and then give it a static interface.

```
IItf_1 test1 = Impromptu.ActLike<IItf_1>(myDynamicObject);
```